# How to replace first character in string

Tags: excel, vba

I have a string in VBA `- Hello how are you`.

I want to replace `-` with something else. How can I do that? I am beginning in VBA. Need help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest way would be to use the replace function.

For example:

```
 Dim yourString As String
 Dim newString As String
 yourString = "- Hello how are you"
 newString = Replace(yourString, "-", "something else")
 MsgBox newString 'returns "something else Hello how are you"
```

If it's always the first character and that character is different for each string you can do something like this:

```
 Dim yourString, subString, replacementString, newString As String
 yourString = "- Hello how are you"
 subString = Right(yourString, Len(yourString) - 1)
 replacementString = "something else"
 newString = replacementString + subString
 MsgBox newString 'returns "something else Hello how are you"
```

Comment: Careful with `Replace` if only the first character is to be examined.

Answer (score 5):

If you are replacing with a single character than using `Mid$` on the LHS is much quicker than appending to a `RIGHT$` manipulation:

(*posting this as not enough detail evident in your question - may be useful for others*)

```
Dim strNew As String
strNew = "- Hello how are you"
Mid$(strNew, 1, 1) = "x"
Debug.Print strNew
```

Comment: I tried to use your method, but editor said that `Mid$(strNew, 1, 1)` part needs variable. How to deal with that replacing `= "x"` presented by You?